# Open application when click on app icon in CallKit

Tags: swift, sinch, callkit

I integrated a Voice call using SINCH SDK, my problem is when phone is on lock screen and i receive an incoming call via CallKit and I answer all things is ok but when I press app icon the application open in VoiceCallController and call run again with ringing sound.

```
class SINCallKitProvider: NSObject, CXProviderDelegate {

var _client: SINClient!
var _provider: CXProvider!
var _acDelegate: AudioContollerDelegate!
var _calls: [UUID : SINCall]
var _muted: Bool


init(withClient: SINClient) {
    
    _client = withClient
    _muted = false
    _acDelegate = AudioContollerDelegate()
    _client.audioController().delegate = _acDelegate
    _calls = [:]
    
    let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "ok")
    config.maximumCallGroups = 2
    config.supportsVideo = false
    config.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    let callkitIcon = UIImage(named: "ok")
    config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(callkitIcon!)
    
    _provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
    
    
    super.init()
    
    _provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(callDidEnd), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "SINCallDidEndNotification"), object: nil)
    
}

func reportNewIncomingCall (call: SINCall) {
    let firstName = currentUser.string(forKey: "firstName")
    let lastName = currentUser.string(forKey: "lastName")
    let fullName = "\(firstName!) \(lastName!)"

    var caller = fullName
    if let call = call.headers["from"] {
        caller = call as! String
    }
    
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: caller)

    _provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: UUID(uuidString: call.callId)!, update: update) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error call \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        self.addNewCall(call: call)
    }
    
}

func addNewCall(call: SINCall) {
    print("Added call \(call.callId)")
    _calls[UUID(uuidString: call.callId)!] = call
}



// Handle cancel/bye event initiated by either caller or callee
@objc func callDidEnd(notification: Notification) {
    
    if let call: SINCall = notification.userInfo![SINCallKey] as? SINCall {
        
        let cause = SINGetCallEndedReason(cause: call.details.endCause)
        
        _provider.reportCall(with: UUID(uuidString: call.callId)!, endedAt: call.details.endedTime, reason: cause)
        
        
        if self.callExist(callId: call.callId) {
            print("CallDidEnd, removing \(call.callId)")
            _calls.removeValue(forKey: UUID(uuidString: call.callId)!)
        }

    } else {
        print("****warning no call was reported")
    }
    
    
}


func callExist (callId: String) -> Bool {
    
    if _calls.count == 0 {
        return false
    }

    for callKitCall in _calls.values {
        if callKitCall.callId == callId {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func activeCalls() -> [SINCall] {
    return Array(_calls.values)
}

func currentEstablishedCall () -> SINCall? {
    let calls = activeCalls()
    
    if calls.count == 1 && calls[0].state == SINCallState.established {
        return calls[0]
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}


//MARK: CXProvider delegate
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("Did activate")
    _client.call()?.provider(provider, didActivate: audioSession)
}

func callForAction(action: CXCallAction) -> SINCall? {
    
    let call = _calls[action.callUUID]
    if call == nil {
        print("Warning no call found for action \(action.callUUID)")
        return nil
    }
    return call
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    print("Answer call action")
    callForAction(action: action)!.answer()
    action.fulfill()
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
    print("end call action")
    callForAction(action: action)!.hangup()
    action.fulfill()
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetMutedCallAction) {
    print("mute call action")

    if _acDelegate.muted {
        _client.audioController().unmute()
    } else {
        _client.audioController().mute()
    }
    action.fulfill()
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("did diactivate audio session")
}


func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
    print("did reset")

}


//MARK: Helpers
func SINGetCallEndedReason(cause: SINCallEndCause) -> CXCallEndedReason {
    switch cause {
    case .error:
        return CXCallEndedReason.failed
    case.denied:
        return CXCallEndedReason.remoteEnded
    case .hungUp:
        return CXCallEndedReason.remoteEnded
    case .timeout:
        return CXCallEndedReason.unanswered
    case .canceled:
        return CXCallEndedReason.unanswered
    case .noAnswer:
        return CXCallEndedReason.unanswered
    case .otherDeviceAnswered:
        return CXCallEndedReason.unanswered
    default:
        break
    }
    
    return CXCallEndedReason.failed
}


}
```

Comment: can you help me with overall code?

Comment: yea can u help us newbie developer by uploading a sample Swift Project for sinch. with background called enable. or could work it together

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that your app doesn't present the correct view when entering your app via the app icon on CallKit locked screen UI?

If that is your problem, one solution could be: you should maintain a list or variable in your callkit provider, just to check if you have any connected call. And your app delegate should listen to applicationWillEnterForeground notification, which will be triggered if user clicks the app icon on callkit UI.

When you receive the applicationWillEnterForeground notification, you check if your callkit provider is holding any active call, if yes, you present the view which shows the ongoing call, otherwise you show whatever view you will show in your current implementation.

The SinchCallKit sample app provides some implementation reference for handling this issue (in objective c though). Please check AppDelegate.m, CallViewController.m and SINCallKitProvider.m in that project.

Comment: by any chance u have swift complete sample project for sinch that already publish.